# Charging during filetransfer

Tags: charging, 6.0-marshmallow, file-transfer

I have recently upgraded my phone from Android 4.3 to 6.0 in my Sony Xperia M.
I'm pretty confused by the new behavior.
Whenever I plug the phone to the USB cable, it is detected in the computer as new connected MTP device but without access to the files (the phone is in the "charging mode".

When I change the connection type in the phone to "file transfer", the charging stops and the file transfer mode hungs somehow after a while of not using the file transfer.

- Why it is not possible to transfer files during charging?
- The hung seem to be some kind of error.

I'm thinking that it would be much better to use adb or some kind of ftp/ssh/whatever server installed inside the phone for file transfers instead of this crappy UI-friendly functionality.

Is there some better way how to work with the phone?

Comment: Hmm, that's weird, my S6 Edge charges while transferring files. Seems like software issue on the manufacturer's side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from [Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/0A-o8m9eAnc) solution posted by M Power, marked as *best answer* - this may help solve the *hung problem* but can't say about *not charging during file transfer*, but going by your description both seem to be related

> .... Secondly, when doing a transfer, the phone must be **unlocked**. This was the problem I was experiencing. I would start a large transfer of photos, then during that time my screen would lock and I would get an error. My screen timeout is typically set to 30 secs so this happened quickly for me. Changing the lock to 30 minutes and checking the phone on occasion solved my problem.

Comment: Well, this means that the phone is not the right gadget to be used for storing data/media. adb is the right choice for me then.

Comment: The post says that it is a *security* measure- I don't have marshmallow but did this fix help? Curiosity